# brew install libxml2 timing out

Tags: homebrew, libxml2

`brew install libxml2` doesn't work for me, and I can't determine why.

```
jzohrab:~ jzohrab$ brew install libxml2 --verbose
==> Downloading ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/libxml2-2.9.0.tar.gz
/usr/bin/curl -f#LA Homebrew 0.9.4 (Ruby 1.8.7-358; Mac OS X 10.8.2) ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/libxml2-2.9.0.tar.gz -C 0 -o /Library/Caches/Homebrew/libxml2-2.9.0.tar.gz.incomplete

curl: (56) Recv failure: Operation timed out
```

I've been trying this for several days, thinking it was a server traffic issue.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same here. Placing a mirror from `http://www.filewatcher.com/m/libxml2-2.9.0.tar.gz.5161069-0.html` into line 5 of `/usr/local/Library/Formula/libxslt.rb` did the trick.

Comment: Thanks @ylluminate.  I tried my original command today without using the mirror and it's downloading.  I'd looked for a mirror as well but couldn't find one.  I'll accept your answer, thanks.